# How to unzip all files in directory using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory, unzip

I want to unzipped all the files from the specific directory but dont know how to do it using shell script.

```
Lgl_Entitiy.txt.zip
Lgl_Entitiy.txt_1.zip
Lgl_Relate.txt.zip
Lgl_Relate.txt_1.zip
Lgl_Name.txt.zip
Lgl_Name.txt_1.zip
```

Comment: After you have retrieved your files with cURL, you can call `unzip` command to uncompress them (see `man unzip`)

Comment: i am not retrieving the files from curl...i just want to unzip the files from directory using curl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install unzip:

`sudo apt install` unzip or `yum install unzip`

Use this in the same directory you want to unzip the files:

```
unzip ‘*.zip’
```

If you want to put the uncompressed files in other directory, then use this:

```
unzip ‘*.zip’ -d /usr/sampleZip/ExampleDir
```

To put it into a shell script:

```
vim shellscript.sh
```

Then the script could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

unzip ‘*.zip’
```

After saving the script, to execute it:

```
./shellscript.sh
```

Comment: i want to use shell script actually instead of unzip commande ...is there any possiblitiy with shell script to unzip files in directory ?

Comment: @Andrew just put that command inside a shell script and execute it (I edited my answer)

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple unzip command.

Let me give you an example:

1. go into the directory where you have the zip files.

```
cd /home/rexter/test
```

2. there are few zip files in this location.

```
ls

1.zip
2.zip
3.zip
```

3. now if you want to unzip them all just type:

```
unzip '*.zip'
```

And its done!

########################

As you want script for the same.
Here it is just edit accordingly

```
#!/bin/bash

cd <path-to-your-directory>

unzip '*.zip'
```

save this file as unzipscript.sh and give executable permission to it using 'sudo chmod +x unzipscript.sh' and then run this script.

Comment: i want to use shell script actually instead of unzip commande ...is there any possiblitiy with shell script to unzip files in directory ?

Comment: Even the shell script will also use unzip and execute the same command. You cannot create a script without using unzip command.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
ZIPDIR=P:\TEST\20211123\
cd "$ZIPDIR"
unzip '*.zip'

Comment: I tried with the below shell script but somehow its not working

Comment: Thats the same just create a script with same command. I have editied the Solution kindly edit accordingly.